# Toggle two different divs with one ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to toggle text from two different `ng-click` events. Thing is, that only text1 OR text2 should show up at the same time. Here is my current code:

HTML:

```
<html lang="de" ng-app="ngToggle">
   <div ng-controller="BlubCtrl">
     <img ng-click="blob=!blob">
     <img ng-click="blub=!blub">

     <div ng-hide="blob">text1</div>
     <div ng-hide="blub">text2</div>
   </div>
<html>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('ngToggle', [])
    .controller('BlubCtrl',['$scope', function($scope){
        $scope.blub = true;
        $scope.blob = true;
}]);
```

Comment: Any reason you don't set your clicks to scope functions instead? Should be rather easy at that point to do what you want.

Comment: ng-switch might be more appropriate here. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch  You also might want to pass a function to your ng-clicks and use blob or blub as an argument. More readable and you won't hide divs when the button is clicked again.

Comment: As matthew Green say , it's 'easy', just use ng-show="sth', and ng-show='!sth". User only 1 variable

Comment: Could you explain a bit more in depth? I'm pretty new to programming and angularjs.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll have a look on the ng-switch function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want the option to have none showing or at most one of the divs then you just need to handle that logic in a function on the scope. That could look like the following.

```
$scope.toggleBlub = function() {
    $scope.blub = !$scope.blub
    $scope.blob = true;
}
$scope.toggleBlob = function() {
    $scope.blob = !$scope.blob
    $scope.blub = true;
}
```

And you would update your clicks to the following.

```
<img ng-click="toggleBlob()">
<img ng-click="toggleBlub()">
```

```js
angular.module('ngToggle', [])
  .controller('BlubCtrl', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {
      $scope.blub = true;
      $scope.blob = true;

      $scope.toggleBlub = function() {
        $scope.blub = !$scope.blub
        $scope.blob = true;
      }
      $scope.toggleBlob = function() {
        $scope.blob = !$scope.blob
        $scope.blub = true;
      }
    }
  ]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="ngToggle" ng-controller="BlubCtrl">
  <button ng-click="toggleBlob()">Blob</button>
  <button ng-click="toggleBlub()">Blub</button>

  <div ng-hide="blob">text1</div>
  <div ng-hide="blub">text2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think to solution from Matthew is a good one, but I find i more relevant to set an `ng-show` instead of `ng-hide`

```
angular.module('ngToggle', [])
  .controller('BlubCtrl', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {
      $scope.blub = false;
      $scope.blob = false;

      $scope.toggleBlub = function() {
        $scope.blub = !$scope.blub
        $scope.blob = false;
      }
      $scope.toggleBlob = function() {
        $scope.blob = !$scope.blob
        $scope.blub = false;
      }
    }
  ]);


<div ng-app="ngToggle" ng-controller="BlubCtrl">
  <button ng-click="toggleBlob()">Blob</button>
  <button ng-click="toggleBlub()">Blub</button>

  <div ng-show="blob">text1</div>
  <div ng-show="blub">text2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think a lot of that depends on the purpose of the `blub` and `blob` variables. If they mean 'hide content' then using `ng-hide="blub"` would be more semantically correct and easier to read than using `ng-show="!blub"`. Of course, if you change the meaning then using show would be more correct.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you explain the advantage of your solution?

Comment: I like to put ng-show when you need to show things, and ng-hide when you need to hide them. `ng-show="!blub"` is not used since blub = false.

Comment: @gr3g Right. But by setting `blub = false` you are changing the meaning of `blub` which may not be correct. It works either way but having a more consistently meaningful variable is more important than if you want to use show or hide, I would think.

Comment: How do you mean? When I think about blub, I think it should be false, because not viewed